# How are ROS debian packages compiled?

Tags: ros, gcc, performance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'd like to know if there's any documentation on the gcc flags used to compile the Debian ROS packages.
I assume -O3 is used everywhere and that sse1-3 is only enabled on those packages which contain rosbuild_check_for_sse(), but I'd prefer to have this documented, to verify whether I need to rebuild it myself to have maximum performance on my machines.

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32363/how-are-ros-debian-packages-compiled?/) by [Daniel Pinyol](https://answers.ros.org/users/470/daniel-pinyol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Stacks using Catkin in Fuerte are compiled using git-buildpackage, i.e. they are based on the common Debian build toolchain.

As far as I know, classical ros stacks are compiled using some home brew scripts that can be found in [rosdeb](http://ros.org/wiki/rosdeb).

I don't expect too much low-level documentation on how to exist, but at least [this](http://ros.org/wiki/rosdeb/DevelopersGuide) page might contain some valuable information.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1